# A fair die is rolled 5 times. What is the probability that a 5 is obtained on at least one of the rolls?

Tags: probability, dice

A fair die is rolled 5 times. What is the probability that a 5 is obtained on at least one of the rolls?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know what is the probability that no $5$ is obtained on any of the rolls?

Comment: The community rules suggest you should demonstrate an attempt to solution, please, write what you've tried and how

Comment: Virtually every posted question that I have seen on MathSE that followed 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), has generated a positive reaction among MathSE reviewers, who then enthusiastically attacked the problem for the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

To find the probability of obtaining a 5 on at least one of the rolls of a fair six-sided die, you can use the complement rule. The complement of the event "getting a 5 on at least one roll" is the event "not getting a 5 on any of the rolls."

The probability of not getting a 5 on a single roll is 5/6 (since there are five outcomes (1, 2, 3, 4, 6) out of six that are not a 5).

Since each roll is independent, the probability of not getting a 5 on any of the five rolls is (5/6)^(5) (raising the probability of a single roll to the power of the number of rolls).

Now, to find the probability of getting a 5 on at least one roll, subtract the probability of not getting a 5 from 1:

P(at least one 5)=1−P(not getting a 5 on any roll)

P(at least one 5)=1−(5/6)^(5)

Calculating this expression will give you the probability of getting at least one 5 in 5 rolls of the fair die.